# How to get real ptz min/max values of an onvif ip camera?

Tags: c#, wsdl, ip-camera, onvif

**Infos:**

Camera model: Amcrest IP2M-841B ip camera

I coded a c# winform app which can connect to any onvif ip camera and send it ptz commands through events such as button clicks.

I'm using the following wsdl for

PTZ: https://www.onvif.org/ver20/ptz/wsdl/ptz.wsdl

MEDIA: http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/media/wsdl/media.wsdl

**Question:**

How does one get the **real min/max ptz values** of my camera **through an onvif command**?

**What I tried so far:**

```
//PTZ
var ptzEndpointAddress = new EndpointAddress($"http://{cameraAddress}/onvif/ptz");
_ptzClient = new PTZClient(commonCustomBinding, ptzEndpointAddress);
_ptzClient.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(commonPasswordDigestBehavior);

//Get configuration options
var configs = _ptzClient.GetConfigurations();
_ptzConfOptions = _ptzClient.GetConfigurationOptions(configs[0].token);
```

...

```
MaxPan = _ptzConfOptions.Spaces.AbsolutePanTiltPositionSpace[0].XRange.Max;
MinPan = _ptzConfOptions.Spaces.AbsolutePanTiltPositionSpace[0].XRange.Min;
MaxTilt = _ptzConfOptions.Spaces.AbsolutePanTiltPositionSpace[0].YRange.Max;
MinTilt = _ptzConfOptions.Spaces.AbsolutePanTiltPositionSpace[0].YRange.Min;
MaxZoom = _ptzConfOptions.Spaces.AbsoluteZoomPositionSpace[0].XRange.Max;
MinZoom = _ptzConfOptions.Spaces.AbsoluteZoomPositionSpace[0].XRange.Min;
```

Here's an example of what I get from these values:
[image: onvif absolute min/max]

But, when I pan my camera to the far left, right, botton or top, I don't get the same values as maximum...

[image: actual min/max 0]

[image: actual min/max 1]

These values make no sense to me...

Answer (score 1):

Request "GetCompatibleConfigurations" in https://www.onvif.org/ver20/ptz/wsdl/ptz.wsdl

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll try to look this request in the near future since i'm no longer working on this problem at the moment. (:

Comment: I am working with onvif a lot on some project and you can ask me about something